# Is it bad UX for a form to be presented in different formats (either in a modal or separate page), depending on context?

Tags: forms, interaction-design, interface, modal

I'm designing an internal tool in which a user, at certain points, will need to fill out a fairly detailed form in order to add a piece of content to our user-facing platform.

However, the challenge I'm facing is that the form is available at different points in the user's journey, and **I'm wondering if I can format the presentation of the form differently (either as a modal or a separate page) depending on where the user is and what they're doing, to cater to separate use cases.** Namely, I'd like to present it within a **modal** when the user is on a page where they'll be engaged with a different, priority task, but needs to quickly fill out the form to create a piece of content, and then resume with the main task.

But elsewhere in the tool, I'd like to present the form on a **separate page** when the user is on the page where all those content pieces live - so that when the user clicks a "+New Content" CTA, they'll be taken to a separate page where they'll fill out the form.

Ultimately, I'm trying to cater to these separate use cases with these different interactions, but is the resulting inconsistency bad? Trying to understand the tradeoff here.

I hope this all makes sense, thanks for taking a look!

Comment: The only downside I see to that is that the devs will have to build two separate treatments. Sign-up is a one-time process, so the user won't see any inconsistency anyway. But I would challenge you, without knowing much about your project, to answer why you wouldn't just use the modal for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that if the information on the form is the same, you can stick with a consistent form of displaying it (I'll pick displaying within a modal too). If the content would be different that your approach is perfect.

In any ways, being consistent would cater for a better user experience and if you must make a trade off, you should probably think of making the form on a separate page very interactive and appear less tasking.